# Alternate method for toFixed function in Java

Tags: java, math

I have the values where the last 2 digits valve must be round figured. This functionality I can achieve in JavaScript **toFixed(6)** . But how we can achieve the same in java code

**Example:**

```
Input=75.74306816000052
Input =26.910038862000476

Output=75.743070
Output=26.910040
```

Code:

```
BigDecimal Output= new BigDecimal(Input).setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
```

But the output values coming hear are

```
75.743068
26.910038
```

Comment: Your Java code seems to return the correct results. Why should the output be 75.743070? That's not correct rounding.

Comment: I read the description of `toFixed`, and it just does standard rounding (nothing about the last 2 digits), so the Java code does exactly the same.

Comment: Javascript's toFixed(6) actually returns 75.743068, same as Java. There must be another part of your code that is further rounding the results to 5 decimal places.

Comment: By the way, what exactly do you mean by "the last 2 digits valve must be round figured"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments under your post already state, the rounding in java is correct and i am not sure what you want to achieve. But this gives you the output you expect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String Input="75.74306816000052";
    String Input2 = "26.910038862000476";
    BigDecimal Output= new BigDecimal(Input).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(Output.setScale(6)); //75.743070
    BigDecimal Output2= new BigDecimal(Input2).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(Output2.setScale(6)); //26.910040
}
```

Comment: Actually, even the Javascript toFixed(6) call returns 75.743068 (same as Java). I don't know where the OP got 75.743070 from.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [**`String::format`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and convert your String to `BigDecimal` like this :

```
String num1 = String.format(Locale.UK, "%.5f", 75.74306816000052);
String num2 = String.format(Locale.UK, "%.5f", 26.910038862000476);
//----------------------------------------^-----------------------

BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(num1);
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(num2);

System.out.println(b1);
System.out.println(b2);
```

This can gives you :

```
75,74307
26,91004
```

---

**EDIT**

Your solution work perfectly but with 5 instead of 6 :

```
BigDecimal Output= new BigDecimal(26.910038862000476).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

This print :

```
26.91004
```